# checkout cart page stock status check in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, cart, frontend, stock-availability

How to check checkout cart page stock status in magento 2.3

my custom code add this file but not working

```
             <?php if ($product->isAvailable()): ?>
                <div class="stock available" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability') ?>">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In Stock') ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability') ?>">
                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of Stock') ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

app/design/frontend/Themename/Magento_checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Files.LineLength.MaxExceeded

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer */

$_item = $block->getItem();
$product = $_item->getProduct();
$isVisibleProduct = $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
/** @var \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $helper */
$helper = $this->helper(Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data::class);
$canApplyMsrp = $helper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($product) && $helper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($product);
?>
<tbody class="cart item">
    <tr class="item-info">
        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Item')) ?>" class="col item">
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()) :?>
                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getProductName()) ?>"
                   tabindex="-1"
                   class="product-item-photo">
            <?php else :?>
                <span class="product-item-photo">
            <?php endif;?>
            <?= $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml() ?>
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()) :?>
                </a>
            <?php else :?>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="product-item-details">
                <strong class="product-item-name">
                    <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()) :?>
                        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl()) ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?></a>
                    <?php else :?>
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </strong>
                <?php if ($_options = $block->getOptionList()) :?>
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) :?>
                            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $block->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                            <dt><?= $block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                            <dd>
                                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])) :?>
                                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_formatedOptionValue['full_view']) ?>
                                <?php else :?>
                                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_formatedOptionValue['value'], ['span', 'a']) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </dd>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </dl>
                <?php endif;?>
                <?php if ($messages = $block->getMessages()) :?>
                    <?php foreach ($messages as $message) :?>
                        <div class= "cart item message <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($message['type']) ?>">
                            <div><?= $block->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?></div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
                <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
                    <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        </td>

        <?php if ($canApplyMsrp) :?>
            <td class="col msrp" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Price')) ?>">
                <span class="pricing msrp">
                    <span class="msrp notice"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('See price before order confirmation.')) ?></span>
                    <?php $helpLinkId = 'cart-msrp-help-' . $_item->getId(); ?>
                    <a href="#" class="action help map"
                       id="<?= ($block->escapeHtmlAttr($helpLinkId)) ?>"
                       data-mage-init='{"addToCart":{
                                            "helpLinkId": "#<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeHtml($helpLinkId)) ?>",
                                            "productName": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeHtml($product->getName())) ?>",
                                            "showAddToCart": false
                                            }
                                        }'
                    >
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("What's this?")) ?></span>
                    </a>
                </span>
            </td>
        <?php else :?>
            <td class="col price" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Price')) ?>">
                <?= $block->getUnitPriceHtml($_item) ?>
            </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <td class="col qty" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>">
            <div class="field qty">
                <div class="control qty">
                    <label for="cart-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty">
                        <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span>
                        <input id="cart-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty"
                               name="cart[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>][qty]"
                               data-cart-item-id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getSku()) ?>"
                               value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getQty()) ?>"
                               type="number"
                               size="4"
                               step="any"
                               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                               class="input-text qty"
                               data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
                               data-role="cart-item-qty"/>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class="col subtotal" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Subtotal')) ?>">
            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp) :?>
                <span class="cart msrp subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else :?>
                <?= $block->getRowTotalHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item-actions">
        <td colspan="4">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getActions($_item) ?>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" />
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_Module', __DIR__);
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_Module">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item;

 use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemResolverInterface;
 use Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Data;
 use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock;
 use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\InterpretationStrategyInterface;

 class Renderer extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer
 {
     protected $stockRegistry;
     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration $productConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder $imageBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
         PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency, \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
         InterpretationStrategyInterface $messageInterpretationStrategy,
         array $data = [],
         ItemResolverInterface $itemResolver = null,
         \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $productConfig, $checkoutSession, $imageBuilder, $urlHelper, $messageManager, $priceCurrency, $moduleManager, $messageInterpretationStrategy, $data, $itemResolver);
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
}

public function isProductAvailable()
{
    $quoteItem = $this->getItem();
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    /* @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockStatusInterface $stockStatus */
    $stockStatus = $this->stockRegistry->getStockStatus($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

    /* @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockStatusInterface $parentStockStatus */
    $parentStockStatus = false;

    /**
     * Check if product in stock. For composite products check base (parent) item stock status
     */
    if ($quoteItem->getParentItem()) {
        $product = $quoteItem->getParentItem()->getProduct();
        $parentStockStatus = $this->stockRegistry->getStockStatus(
            $product->getId(),
            $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId()
        );
    }

    if ($stockStatus) {
        if ($stockStatus->getStockStatus() === Stock::STOCK_OUT_OF_STOCK
            || $parentStockStatus && $parentStockStatus->getStockStatus() == Stock::STOCK_OUT_OF_STOCK
        ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

> app/design/frontend/Themename/Magento_checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

```
<?php if ($block->isProductAvailable()): ?>
    <div class="stock available  col-lg-4" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability') ?>">
        <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In Stock') ?></span>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="stock unavailable  col-lg-4" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability') ?>">
        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of Stock') ?></span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```